# Common chart legends for multiple charts in React-Chart.js using Cube js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, cube

There are multiple trend line charts that show data for the last 13 months, which are created in react-charts-2 and cube js. I want to display legends that should be common for those charts. It should show/hide the same series in all charts on click of the legend. ([image: This is the sample I have done])

In this when clicking on legend buttons, handled by hiding series from the dataset, Actually the default chart legend should be strike-out instead of hiding the dataset. Is it possible?